# Is it possible to apply filters on a model inside a view in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

Is it possible to apply filters on a model inside a view's code:

I use axlsx to generate Excel and I tried something like this inside my `myview.xlsx.axlsx` file:

```
fs = MyModel.where(:Column1 => v1, :Column2 => v2)
puts fs[0].Column1
```

I got an error

```
undefined method Column1 for nil:NilClass
```

I am pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my filter so I wonder is it legal to have such a filter inside a view (and if such filters should only be placed inside a controller instead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's legal, yet not advisable to use queries in the view. It's better to move them to a controller and even better to wrap them in a method inside the model.

In your case it looks that the query returns an empty collection, and that's why `fs[0]` is `nil` and you cannot call a method on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can have such code in views, although you should try to avoid having logic in the view and move it to the controller or a helper. The problem here is that the active record relation is empty:

```
fs = MyModel.where(:Column1 => v1, :Column2 => v2) #=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
fs[0] #=> nil
```

You can use `try` to avoid that an exception is raised if the relation is empty and return `nil` instead:

```
fs[0].try(:Column1) #=> nil
```